# Node.JS - Converting UNIX Timestamp to Time - timezones shift

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, time, timestamp

I have a function, that converts timestamp to time:

```
function convertUnixTimeToTime(UNIX_timestamp) {
    var a = new Date(UNIX_timestamp);
    var fin_hour = String(a.getHours())
    if (fin_hour.length == 1) {
        fin_hour = '0' + fin_hour;
    }
    var fin_minutes = String(a.getMinutes())
    if (fin_minutes.length == 1) {
        fin_minutes = '0' + fin_minutes;
    }
    var time = fin_hour + ':' + fin_minutes;
    return time;
}
```

I'm tesing my app locally, my computer's timeshift is +4.
When I try to get current time from node app:

```
console.log('Current time is: ' + convertUnixTimeToTime(new Date().getTime()));
```

I get my **current local** time. As I supposed, Date().getTime() should return absolute UNIX time in milliseconds. My function convertUnixTimeToTime() does not specify any time shift, that's why I should get clear time without any shifts. Why am I getting shifted +4 time? Thanks.

Comment: Try `.getUTCHours()` and `getUTCMinutes()` instead of just `getHours()` and `getMinutes()`.

Comment: Also JavaScript works in miliseconds, not seconds. So it should be: `var a = new Date(UNIX_timestamp*1000);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getHours` and `getMinutes` functions always return local time.  The `new Date(new Date().getTime())` is confusing more than anything else - its the same as `new Date()` - it does not change anything about timezones.

To get what you're looking for, use `getUTCHours` and `getUTCMinutes`.

Answer (score 1):

Because [`Date.getHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) and [`Date.getMinutes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMinutes) by definition return local time?